# Is there a way to deploy x86 images on a Apple silicon (ARM) using docker stack?

Tags: docker, arm, docker-swarm, apple-m1, apple-silicon

We have a Docker stack compose file using services built for **x86**. To get our dev-setup running locally on my **Apple Silicon/M1/ARM chip**, I tried to deploy the stack using docker stack deploy. The services won't run and fail citing the unsupported architecture on the node. Is there a way to emulate an intel architecture on my docker swarm node? Or to run the x86 services using rosetta?

The `--platform` flag [mentioned in the docs](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/mac/apple-silicon/) does not seem to work for the Docker stack.

Comment: Note the difference between Silicon and Silicone.  Silicon -> used to manufacture integrated circuits. Silicone -> Sealants, bake wear and breast implants.

Comment: *"Docker Desktop for Apple silicon ... allows you to build and run images for both x86 and ARM architectures"*: https://docs.docker.com/desktop/mac/apple-silicon/

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have found a solution: `docker stack` deploys pre-built images. You will get an "unsupported platform" error for any service which doesn't have an arm-build.

Using the `--platform linux/amd64` trick doesn't work for docker stack because it has no `--platform` option. What you need to do instead is:

1. make sure the services of the stack are locally available (for example by executing docker stack deploy with you docker stack yml file, which again will fail to start the services but download them).
2. add `--resolve-image "never"` to your docker stack deploy, for example:  `docker stack deploy --resolve-image "never" --compose-file=./stack.yml`
3. Now the services will started, using rosetta/qemu emulation in the background for the x86 services. This is not advised and can lead to faulty behavior and bad performance. For example, in my case the x86 keycloak image would start but not work. In those cases, it is necessary to build the service locally for arm.

Comment: Thanks! I've found that `--resolve-image "changed"` also works

Answer (score 0):

The following command worked for me:

```
docker run --platform linux/amd64 {imagename}
```